# Cloth simulation weird behaviour - Blender 2.8

Tags: cloth-simulation

im trying to do some cloth simulation in blender 2.8, and everytime i check self colision option my cloth automaticly deforms to extremly wrinkled something.

Note: It only happens when i use self colision, and everything works just fine in blender 2.79.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and read elsewhere that wrinkling can happen because of small distances between vertices (or something like that).

My solution here was scaling up the whole scene 10x, applying transformation (Ctrl-A) and then running the cloth animation/simulation...

(It even appears that simulations runs faster that way, too.)